# CPU idle % vs load average

Tags: unix, cpu-usage

I have read all related questions but have not found an adequate answer. How can both CPU idle % and load average high at the same time? What is the relation of the two measurements. Is there way to improve the load averages by make use of CPU idle? Thanks in advance.

```
/# top 4 10
load averages:  7.51,  7.75,  7.42;                    up 26+20:51:52  14:51:35
51 processes: 44 sleeping, 6 on cpu, 1 swapped
CPU states: 76.2% idle,  5.9% user, 17.9% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Memory: 1024M phys mem, 3267M free mem, 2048M total swap, 1519M free swap

   PID USERNAME LWP PRI NICE  SIZE   RES STATE    TIME    CPU COMMAND
  1101 mysql     21  59    0  133M  114M cpu/19 685:21  1.36% mysqld
 47426 www        1  28    0   43M   22M cpu/1    0:13  0.38% httpd
 47543 www        1  30    0   42M   21M cpu/13   0:11  0.37% httpd
 48459 www        1  16    0   41M   19M sleep    0:00  0.37% httpd


/# mysqladmin -uroot -ppass extended-status | grep Threads
| Threads_cached                           | 0           |
| Threads_connected                        | 9           |
| Threads_created                          | 455358      |
| Threads_running                          | 3           |
/#
```

---

EDIT a day later.
According to all answers the system is *unstressed* but we still experience long latency from websites on the system. The latency normally sub-second now is several seconds, sometimes in teens or more. Would it be because of i/o? If it is what would your suggestions? Thanks again.

```
~# iostat c 1
   tty         cpu
 tin tout  us sy dt id
   0  245   4 30  0 66
   0   32   4 15  0 81
   0   24   3 18  0 79
   0   24   4 25  0 71
   0   24   3 27  0 71
   0   24   2 22  0 75
   0   24   3 21  0 77
   0   24   2 20  0 77
   0   24   4 17  0 79
   0   24   5 21  0 74
   0   24   5 15  0 80
   0   24   6 11  0 83
   0   24   8  8  0 84
   0   25   8 10  0 82
   0   24   7 12  0 81
   0   24   5 16  0 78
   0   24   4 17  0 79
   0   24   2 14  0 83
   0   24   2 13  0 84
```

Comment: with an unstressed system, its harder to make recommendations. Based on what you've posted, it looks like your system is doing the right thing. You need to amp up your usage so you can see where the bottlenecks are. Also there are other higher 'follower count' tags that cpu-usage. Maybe 'performance' or 'testing'. Good luck.

Comment: What do mean by _unstressed system_, I mean what in the provided data makes you say so. Do you also mean the system is ok as it is? If I try to stress, or amping up the usage :) can you suggest a way?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "websites on the system". Do you mean multiple websites are running on the same server, or are you connecting to remote websites? Again, you'll get better answers by spending some time looking for tags with more followers than your `cpu-usage`. This has really turned into a different question, and you'd do well to post a new question more tightly focused to the problem at hand. Finally, replace iostat output with small sample of vmstat output. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to revise your conception of what a 'high' load average is.  Since you have something running on cpu/19, you have at least 19 CPU threads in your system -- probably 24 or 32.  So to get the idle down close to 0, you'll need a load average of MORE than that.  With only ~7, you'll only be able to keep at most around 1/4 of the CPU threads busy, so the other 75% will be idle.

Comment: @ngungo : This is what I'm talking about. A system idle at ~70% is an unstressed system (in my opinion). "Amping up" for testing requires planning. If you have a dev system, then ask "how can I simulate a 10X or 20X my current load, and what do I need to obtain that? Bigger input files? Fake user inputs (if a website), or ???. Only you know your system. There are many books about performance testing. If you expect your system's use to grow by 4X (which ~might~ bring your idle time down to 5%), then it is better to do you testing now, rather than when you system has a 3 minute response time.

Comment: :) Thanks Chris for quick response. I subscribe to a 1 CPU and busting, 1GB memory Joyent's SmartMachine Plus instant if this info would enhance any understanding to my question. Your answer lead me to another question, how do I know the max CPU threads?

Comment: @shellter: I got you. Thanks for the hints. I think I can do that. I read it somewhere that the load average should be around 3 per CPU. 5 is fairly high.

Comment: @ngungo: depends on the system.  On linux `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will tell you

Comment: Hmm... I tried that already. My system does not have /proc/cpuinfo file. I have to look around more. Thanks.

Comment: @shellter, I have edited the original question with more info, would you please take a look.